# Getting Credentials of Current User in Jenkins Pipeline Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job that needs to be triggered manually by a logged-in LDAP account. The job contains a step that syncs a git repo, in which the same LDAP account is used for git credentials.

Is it possible to get the `credentialsId` of the person who is currently logged in and is triggering a job? I'm imagining code like this:

```
def credential = getCurrentUserCredential() // ???
git credentialsId: credential, url: 'git.repo'
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you

```
BUILD_CAUSE_JSON=$(curl --silent ${BUILD_URL}/api/json | tr "{}" "\n" | grep "Started by")
BUILD_USER_ID=$(echo $BUILD_CAUSE_JSON | tr "," "\n" | grep "userId" | awk -F\" '{print $4}')
BUILD_USER_NAME=$(echo $BUILD_CAUSE_JSON | tr "," "\n" | grep "userName" | awk -F\" '{print $4}')
```